# What's the purpose of $item in taxonomy_field_is_empty($item, $field)?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Please explain:

```
taxonomy_field_is_empty($item, $field)
```

`$field` - this is name of field

`$item` - what is it ???

I want to use on my function for check if tags field empty in node we don't show other articles, show otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*With the help of @Clive*

I think that's not the way, `taxonomy_field_is_empty` is an implementation of [`hook_field_is_empty()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_is_empty/7), which is used to

> Define what constitutes an empty item for a field type.

`$item` is:

> An item that may or may not be empty.

An `item` is the data for a specific field entry, so what you'd find in, for example, `$node->field_tags['und'][0]` in your code example.

If you have access to the `$node` variable and your field is named `field_tags`you can do this:

```
//Recover all the items
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_tags');
//If there is not a tag, then do something    
if (count($items) == 0) {
  echo "field empty";
}
```

Or

```
//If there is not a tag, then do something
if(count($node->field_tags[LANGUAGE_NONE]) == 0) {
  echo "field empty";
}
```

Comment: That'll tell you how many languages the field is translated into, not how many items it contains

Comment: @Clive I will test it now because, I test the code in a multilingual site, give some minutes

Comment: Save yourself the time, it should be: `$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_tags'); if (count($items) == 0) { ...`, or a version using `EntityMetadataWrapper`. For 'raw' PHP it would be `if (count($node->field_tags[LANGUAGE_NONE]) == 0) { `, but that's not recommended

Comment: Good stuff, if you want to copy the information from my answer into yours that'd be good, better to have one answer with all the info in than split across 2. If you do, let me know when you're done so I can delete mine

Comment: @clive ok, I will do this now, give some minutes

Comment: Yeah no hurry :)